# FragmentManager can't resolve in androidx

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-appcompat, androidx

**FragmentManager** and **beginTransaction** cannot resolve in androidx

```
   FragmentManager fM = getSupportFragmentManager();

   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fM.beginTransaction();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an [`androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity) or [`androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment) just use the import:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
```

The class is inside the `androidx.fragment:fragment:x.x.x` library which is a dependency of the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`.
Just use:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

Comment: thanks, now it's perfectly working after adding this dependency.

Comment: Hi @KhadijaHameed if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.